# How to tell TestCafe to wait after navigateTo method?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have following test in TestCafe:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const TEST_URL = process.env.TEST_URL;

fixture('/').page(`${TEST_URL}/`);

test(`users should be able to view the '/' page`, async (t) => {
    await t
        .navigateTo(TEST_URL)
        .expect(Selector('H1').withText('All Users').exists).ok()
});
```

And this test fail:

```
/
 ✖ users should be able to view the '/' page

   1) AssertionError: expected false to be truthy

      Browser: Chrome 59.0.3071 / Mac OS X 10.12.5

          5 |fixture('/').page(`${TEST_URL}/`);
          6 |
          7 |test(`users should be able to view the '/' page`, async (t) => {
          8 |    await t
          9 |        .navigateTo(TEST_URL)
       > 10 |        .expect(Selector('H1').withText('All Users').exists).ok()
         11 |});
         12 |
```

Problem is that page don't fully load and there is no h1 tag (which is rendered from React component) but I don't know how to tell TestCafe to wait for page to load.

I tried this:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const TEST_URL = process.env.TEST_URL;

fixture('/').page(`${TEST_URL}/`);

test(`users should be able to view the '/' page`, async (t) => {
    await t.expect(Selector('H1').withText('All Users').exists).ok()
});
```

which works but I need for some test to use navigateTo so I would like to know what to change so that version of test with navigateTo also works.

I tried to set await for every line like this:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

const TEST_URL = process.env.TEST_URL;

fixture('/').page(`${TEST_URL}/`);

test(`users should be able to view the '/' page`, async (t) => {
    await t.navigateTo(TEST_URL)
    await t.expect(Selector('H1').withText('All Users').exists).ok()
});
```

but that error is same.

Comment: Luka Lopusina. I cannot reproduce your scenario in a simple example. Could you provide a URL to your page?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the `TEST_URL` variable. If it contains bare IP address (e.g., `'xxx.xx.x.xxx'`), [`navigateTo`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/navigate.html) will redirect the browser to `'http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/xxx.xx.x.xxx'` because the `navigateTo` action treats this string as a relative path.

To solve the problem, include the protocol in the `TEST_URL` string, e.g. `'http://xxx.xx.x.xxx'`.